# How to change the font for metauml?

Tags: metapost, metauml, emp

I am using the `emp` package in order to use `metauml` for drawing UML-models. So far so good.

this is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{emp}

\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\else
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{empfile}
\begin{empcmds}
input metauml;
\end{empcmds}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{emp}[classdiag](20, 20)
Class.A("A")()();
Class.B("B")()();
B.e = A.w + (-20, 0);
drawObjects(A, B);
link(inheritance)(B.e -- A.w);
\end{emp}
\caption{A class diagram}
\end{figure}

\end{empfile}
\end{document}
```

It looks like the text in the graph is using Time New Roman.

How can I change the font to something else?

I already tried something like `\empaddtoTeX{\usepackage[default]{lato}}` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MetaUML uses a very low level text management. The font used is defined in the file `metauml_defaults.mp` which contains

```
if known _metauml_defaults_mp: 
  expandafter endinput 
fi;
_metauml_defaults_mp:=1;

% txbtt

if not known metauml_defaultFont:
    string metauml_defaultFont;
    metauml_defaultFont  := "ptmr8r";
fi;

if not known metauml_defaultFontOblique:
    string metauml_defaultFontOblique;
    metauml_defaultFontOblique  := "ptmro8r";
fi;

if not known metauml_defaultFontBold:
    string metauml_defaultFontBold;
    metauml_defaultFontBold  := "ptmb8r";
fi;

if not known metauml_defaultFontBoldOblique:
    string metauml_defaultFontBoldOblique;
    metauml_defaultFontBoldOblique  := "ptmbo8r";
fi;
```

You can find it in your system, copy it in the current directory and modify the font names. Notice that support for encodings is *inexistent*, so for accented characters you're out of luck. What fonts are really supported depends, I believe, on the Metapost version you're using.

A different way to set the fonts is to write

```
\begin{empcmds}
_metauml_defaults_mp := 1 ; % avoid loading metauml_defaults.mp
string metauml_defaultFont;
metauml_defaultFont  := "cmr10";
string metauml_defaultFontOblique;
metauml_defaultFontOblique  := "cmti10";
string metauml_defaultFontBold;
metauml_defaultFontBold  := "cmbx10";
string metauml_defaultFontBoldOblique;
metauml_defaultFontBoldOblique  := "cmbxti10";
input metauml;
\end{empcmds}
```

where I've used the usual Computer Modern fonts.

A complete version using the Lato fonts would be:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{emp}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{empfile}
\begin{empcmds}
_metauml_defaults_mp:=1;
string metauml_defaultFont;
metauml_defaultFont:="Lato-Reg-t1";
string metauml_defaultFontOblique;
metauml_defaultFontOblique  := "Lato-RegIta-t1";
string metauml_defaultFontBold;
metauml_defaultFontBold  := "Lato-Bol-t1";
string metauml_defaultFontBoldOblique;
metauml_defaultFontBoldOblique  := "Lato-BolIta-t1";
input metauml;
\end{empcmds}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{emp}[classdiag](20, 20)
Class.A("Abcde")()();
Class.B("Bmno")()();
B.e = A.w + (-20, 0);
drawObjects(A, B);
link(inheritance)(B.e -- A.w);
\end{emp}
\caption{A class diagram}
\end{figure}

\end{empfile}
\end{document}
```

(I've changed the way you declare the extensions for the PDF setting.)

There's a final note to be made. MetaUML font management relies on printing strings, not on interaction between Metapost and TeX. So the choice of fonts is somewhat restricted and has important limitations.

Fonts in OT1 encoding, such as `cmr10` have a "lslashslash" in the position of the space, so a MetaUML label with a space ("ABC DEF") would result in something like

> ABC-DEF

Fonts in T1 encoding have a "visible space" in that position, and the string above would become

> ABC└┘DEF

(with the symbol at the baseline).

So the choice, in case spaces are needed, is limited to fonts in 8r encoding (which is why the default font is `ptmr8r`).

Comment: Thanks that works nicely! The only problem is when I use whitespaces, then I get a skewed hyphen instead. Is there a way to find out the possible codes for the fonts?

Comment: It can be worse than that! With the Lato fonts, you'd get a "visible space". I don't think there's much to do about this, sorry: the way MetaUML manages text is really too primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Some 80 months on, this is problem is much easier to solve with `luamplib`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib, luatex85}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainfont{Lato}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\everymplib{input metauml; beginfig(0);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document}

\section{UML diagrams}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \[
    \begin{mplibcode} 
        Class.A("Class A with spaces")()();
        Class.B("B")()();
        B.e = A.w + (-42, 0);
        drawObjects(A, B);
        link(inheritance)(B.e -- A.w);
    \end{mplibcode}
  \]
    \caption{A Class diagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Notes

- Using `luamplib` means you have to compile with `lualatex`
- and therefore use `fontspec` to set the fonts
- but you can use any system-installed font
- `mplibtextextlabel{enable}` makes MetaUML / Metapost put all text strings through `textext()` which means they are typeset in the same environment as the rest of the doc
- `everymplib` saves you typing the same thing each time..