# Minipage inside MetaUML Activity Diagram

Tags: minipage, metauml

I want to use Minipage environment inside MetaUML Activity Diagrams. The following MWE will not compile (tried mpost and mptopdf). When using the next line instead of the minipage-line, compiling is OK.

```
input metauml;
input TEX;

beginfig(1);
  Activity.x("                                                  ");
  drawObject(x);
  item(iAssoc)(btex \begin{minipage}{40mm} $\alpha$ \end{minipage} etex)(obj.c = x.c);
% item(iAssoc)(btex $\alpha$ etex)(obj.c = x.c);
endfig;

end
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.     A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: As far as I know, MetaUML only accepts strings and not `btex...etex` for the labels; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74455/4427