# How do I change the font of a graphic in latex?

Tags: graphics, metapost, metauml

I started working on a simple UML diagram for a final Java project. I started by reading a lot on the metauml github repository and [this example in particular](https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML/wiki/Class). As you can see by the attached image, the serif font looks really out of place within the UML diagram. I'm able to highlight and copy the text within the document, so I assume I can change the font. How do you recommend I do this?

TLDR: How do I change the font within an `\includegraphics{...}` statement?

My metapost document:

```
input metauml;
beginfig(1);
    Class.U("User")
    ("- userId : int")
    ("+ getUserId : int");

    Class.A("App")
    ("- appId : int")
    ("+ getAppId : int");

    topToBottom(45)(U, A);
    drawObject(U);
    drawObject(A);
endfig;
end;
```

My latex document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example.1}
\end{document}
```

The output of `mpost example.mp && pdflatex example.tex`:

[image: Simple UML Diagram inside latex]

Comment: you can not change the font using `\includegraphics` you need to go back and generate a different image using different fonts,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle by "generate a different image" do you mean within my metapost file? I'm quite new to metapost and latex so apologies if it is a stupid question.

Comment: yes, I don't really know metapost but someone will be able to help

Comment: This question is a near duplicate of this one:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74432/15036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the font to use for MetaUML prior to loading.

```
string metauml_defaultFont;
metauml_defaultFont := "texnansi-lmr10";
input metauml;
```

This will use Latin Modern instead of the default Times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What fonts does MetaUML search from? I'm sure there is an easy way for me to find a list...

Answer (score 0):

I had great fun trying to change the settings within your mwe and you can easily change the first "Class" line to any suitable font as here on the left where I have gone for a SANS serif (Helvetica)
Prior to Henri 's answer I had resorted to easily changing the font by simple quick and dirty find and paste in the ps file see results on the right

[image]

I have taken the liberty of combining both approaches here (the first two lines are as suggested by Henri and thus his answer is "correct" for your Question.

```
string metauml_defaultFont;
metauml_defaultFont := "phvb8rn";
input metauml;

beginfig(1);
    Class.U("User")
    ("- userId : int")
    ("+ getUserId : int");
U.info.foreColor := (.9, .7, .7);
U.info.iName.iFont.name := "phvb8rn";

    Class.A("App")
    ("- appId : int")
    ("+ getAppId : int");
A.info.foreColor := (.7, .7, .9);
A.info.iName.iFont.name := "phvb8rn";

    topToBottom(45)(U, A);
    drawObject(U);
    drawObject(A);
endfig;
end;
```

Font names can be found in http://tug.org/fontname/fontname.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still just getting into metapost but this is all really exiting for me. Hopefully other people can find this useful if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

If `lualatex` is an option for you, you can get a much simpler work flow, and better consistency between `metaUML` output and the rest of your document, by using `luamplib` to include your diagrams in your LaTeX document directly.

Here is an example, with some dummy text, and using [Fira Sans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fira_Sans) to show consistency between the figure and the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib, luatex85}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\everymplib{input metauml; beginfig(0);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document}

\section{UML diagrams}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \[
    \begin{mplibcode} 
        Class.U("User") 
        ("- userId : int") 
        ("+ getUserId : int");

        Class.A("App")
        ("- appId : int")
        ("+ getAppId : int");

        topToBottom(45)(U, A);
        drawObject(U);
        drawObject(A);
    \end{mplibcode}
  \]
\caption{My UML diagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this on my system with `lualatex` I get:

[image]

### Notes

- including `luamplib` forces you to compile with `lualatex`
- and to use `fontspec` to change the font.
- You can use any of your system-installed fonts
- The `\mplibtextextlabel{enable}` line is the vital one; this option tells the underlying MP engine in `luamplib` to pass any `string` through `textext()` so that it is compiled in the same environment as the rest of your doc.
- Using the `\everymplib` and `\everyendmplib` options let you cut down on some boiler plate in each picture.
- The `mblibcode` environment produces a LaTeX box (that essentially looks like one big character to TeX), so to get it nicely centered and spaced in the `figure` environment, you can put it in a math display environment as I've shown.